# PHP unit causing failure when using at(0) and at(1) in magento 2.4.5

Tags: magento2.4.5, phpunit

I upgraded my site from 2.3.6-p1 to 2.4.5-p1 enterprise edition.

code :

```
 $serialNumber->expects($this->at(0))
            ->method('getSerialnumber')
            ->willReturn(null);
 $serialNumber->expects($this->at(1))
            ->method('getSerialnumber')
            ->willReturn(666)
```

;

When I am running PHP unit test case for my custom module throws following error

The at() matcher has been deprecated. It will be removed in PHPUnit 10. Please refactor your test to not rely on the order in which methods are invoked.

So I replaced it with once like below

```
$serialNumber->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getSerialnumber')
            ->willReturn(null);
$serialNumber->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getSerialnumber')
            ->willReturn(666)

;
```

But now I got error like

```
getSerialNumber() was not expected to be called more than once.
```

Please help

I tried to replace the at(0) & at(1) to once()
but still facing error

Expected :
The test case should succeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way, it will call exactly twice and on willReturnOnConsecutiveCalls you inform the return for each one:

```
$serialNumber->expects( $this->exactly( 2 ) )
            ->method('getSerialnumber')
            // ->withConsecutive() // this is just in case you need to pass a different parameter for each time you call this method
            ->willReturnOnConsecutiveCalls( null, 777 );
```